# Markedly faster to access a numpy array 'arr' than 'arr[:]'

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

In the following scenario, why is it notably faster to access `arr` than `arr[:]` or `arr[::]`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (512, 512))

In [3]: %timeit arr
30.8 ns ± 2.43 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit arr[:]
204 ns ± 0.588 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit arr[::]
204 ns ± 1.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [8]: np.all(arr == arr[:])
Out[8]: True

In [9]: np.all(arr == arr[::])
Out[9]: True
```

Aren't all the above approaches accessing a continuous block of elements in memory? Accessing a discontinuous block in memory `arr[::2]` is slower than `arr[:]`, but only marginally so compared to the differences between `a` and `a[:]`.

```
In [10]: %timeit arr[::2]
221 ns ± 2.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `arr` nor `arr[:]` actually *access* the array's buffer. `arr` merely loads a reference to the array, while `arr[:]` constructs a new object backed by the same buffer. `arr[:]` is much more expensive, what with the object creation, but it still doesn't actually do anything with the backing buffer.

Comment: Your remarks also apply to `arr[::2]`. This is slower due to extra work parsing the index.